# Accessing field of object given by name JSTL

Tags: struts, jstl

How do I access field of object which name is given by attribute in jstl?

Let's say in normal case, when it's not given by attribute I'd do it like so:

```
<c:forEach var='varName' items='${realFormName.listFieldName}'>
 ...
```

However since in this case I have to access field of object given by name setup code looks more like this:

```
<c:set var="formName" value="realFormName" />
```

Now i want to iterate over listFieldItem of object given by formName variable. How do i do that? These, for example don't work:

```
<c:forEach var='varName' items='${formName.listFieldName}'>
<c:forEach var='varName' items='${${formName}".listFieldName"}'>
```

So is there a simple way to do it?

Ok, i solved it. For me this worked:

```
<c:set var="form" value="${sessionScope[formName]}"></c:set>
```

It got object represented by formName from session scope and i was able to use it normally.

Comment: just go with struts tags... :)